# Is Kafka Stream StateStore global over all instances or just local?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In Kafka Stream `WordCount` example, it uses `StateStore` to store word counts. If there are multiple instances in the same consumer group, the `StateStore` is global to the group, or just local to an consumer instance?

Thnaks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This depends on your view on a state store.

1. In Kafka Streams a state is shared and thus each instance holds part of the overall application state. For example, using DSL stateful operator use a local RocksDB instance to hold their shard of the state. Thus, with this regard the state is local.
2. On the other hand, all changes to the state are written into a Kafka topic. This topic does not "live" on the application host but in the Kafka cluster and consists of multiple partition and can be replicated. In case of an error, this changelog topic is used to recreate the state of the failed instance in another still running instance. Thus, as the changelog is accessible by all application instances, it can be considered to be global, too.

Keep in mind, that the changelog is the **truth** of the application state and the local stores are basically caches of shards of the state.

Moreover, in the WordCount example, a record stream (the data stream) gets partitioned by words, such that the count of one word will be maintained by a single instance (and different instances maintain the counts for different words).

For an architectural overview, I recommend http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html

Also this blog post should be interesting http://www.confluent.io/blog/unifying-stream-processing-and-interactive-queries-in-apache-kafka/

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax Great answer, +1. How many partitions does this changelog topic have?

Comment: We create one partition per shard. This is determined by the number of input topic partitions. If you consume a single input topic with 5 partitions, we create 5 shards and thus the changelog topic also has 5 partitions.

Comment: Message published to "streams-plaintext-input" comes with a null key and sentence as the value. In this case either of the instances can get the message. How can a valid count be computed if each instance keeps the count of a word?

Comment: You would need to split each sentence into words, putting the words as key, and than count: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/wordcount/WordCountDemo.java (ie, data would be re-distributed base on word to make sure same words end up on same instance.)

Comment: Thanks that makes a few things clear. So does the groupBy (word) create a message with word as Key and null value into an internal topic? And then a consumer is created of that topic receives the words keeps the count? Will the number of partitions of this internal topic be equal to the partitions of the "streams-plaintext-input" topic?
https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-streams-examples/blob/4.1.x/src/main/java/io/confluent/examples/streams/WordCountLambdaExample.java

Comment: `.groupBy((key, value) -> value)` only sets a new key; the existing value is kept (it's not set to `null`). Yes, the data is written to an internal repartition topic. Yes, counting happens after the repartition topic is consumed downstream. Yes, the repartition topic has the same number of partitions as the input topic.

Comment: What if one more worker is added or removed. How would partitioning logic work in that case ?

Comment: If you add a `KafkaStreams` instance, a rebalance will happen and some tasks (including their state and corresponding partitions) would be moved to the new instance.

Answer (score 3):

If worth mentioning that there is a [GlobalKTable improvement proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=67633649)

> GlobalKTable will be fully replicated once per KafkaStreams instance.
>   That is, each KafkaStreams instance will consume all partitions of the
>   corresponding topic.

From the Confluent Platform's mailing list, I've got this information

> You could start
>   prototyping using Kafka 0.10.2 (or trunk) branch...

0.10.2-rc0 already has GlobalKTable!

Here's the [actual PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/2244).

And the person that told me that was Matthias J. Sax ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use a Processor instead of Transformer, for all the transformations you want to perform on the input topic, whenever there is a usecase of lookingup data from GlobalStateStore . Use `context.forward(key,value,childName)` to send the data to the downstream nodes. `context.forward(key,value,childName)` may be called multiple times in a `process()` and `punctuate()` , so as to send multiple records to downstream node. If there is a requirement to update GlobalStateStore, do this only in **Processor** passed to `addGlobalStore(..)` because, there is a GlobalStreamThread associated with GlobalStateStore, which keeps the state of the store consistent across all the running kstream instances.