# Kafka Streams:Aggregate hourly message in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-streams

I have use case where for every second 5k messages are sent to a kafka topic,On the Kafka consumer side I need to aggregate all message for that hour and write files hourly.We are just getting started in Kafka Streams and wondering whether this use case to aggregate message hourly is a right fit for Kafka streams.
Thanks!

Comment: It's certainly possible, yes. What issues are you having?

Comment: you could do that with Kafka Streams by implementing `Transformer` with `processorContext.schedule(..)`. please take a look at example (your case is simpler than in example, as you need only write data to file inside punctuator): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628143/how-to-process-a-kstream-in-a-batch-of-max-size-or-fallback-to-a-time-window/53696566#53696566

Comment: Thanks for your comments @cricket_007 and Vasiliy. I will try and keep you posted.