# Kafka streams processor api single vs batch records processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

**Question 1:** Does kafka streams processor api allows both single and batch record processing ( or it is always batch record processing internally ) ?

**Question 2:** What config or setting is needed to set single or batch processing and how to implement batch processing ( snippet, link) using kafka streams processor api ?

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Streams processor api processes a single record at a time initially, but you could use state stores with `Transformer` for stateful operations for achieving batching.
I guess you need batching by both size and time (e.g. if during 5 seconds batch size not reached, propagate data what we already collected). If so, please take a look at example [How to process a KStream in a batch of max size or fallback to a time window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53696566/2335775). If you need time-based aggregation (and not by size), please take a look at [windowing](https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#windowing).

Actually, you don't need some specific properties for using processor api (only regular props for Kafka Streams like `bootstrap.servers`, `application.id`, `auto.offset.reset` etc.), and only for batching you need to declare a state store.