# Is Kafka global store visible from multiple instances of app

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

My question is - I have Kafka stream processing micro service which listens to multiple topics. Aggregates the state from multiple topics and stores in state store. We send that aggregated message ahead to down stream system. Down stream system will response back with other message on different Kafka topic. Need to create global state store which is visible for all my micro service instances. Is it possible to achieve same in karka using global store ? Can I get sample code example on how to create one ?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/interactive-queries.html#querying-remote-state-stores-for-the-entire-app

Comment: I am asking about streambuilder.addGlobalStore(). If we add global store using this option then is that store visible accross multiple instances of given app?

Answer (score 0):

Quoted from documentation

> The state that is locally available on any given instance is only a subset of the application’s entire state. Querying the local stores on an instance will only return data locally available on that particular instance.

An in this instance, to query across instances, you must expose the `application.server`, as discussed in the link in the comments. Also relevant: [Is Kafka Stream StateStore global over all instances or just local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40274884/is-kafka-stream-statestore-global-over-all-instances-or-just-local)

However, [`GlobalKTable` has a full copy of all data on each instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45975755/what-are-the-differences-between-ktable-vs-globalktable-and-leftjoin-vs-outerj)